# Create React component that returns partial semantic-ui grid row

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I want to have components of a template broken out and getting compile errors when using semantic-ui. (Unexpected token (11:12))

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Label, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class StatusLine extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = props.fyrevm;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column width={8}>
                    <Container textAlign='right'>
                        <Label sub>Score</Label><span>{this.state.score}</span>
                        <Label sub>Turn</Label><span>{this.state.turn}</span>
                        <Label sub>Time</Label><span>{this.state.time}</span>
                    </Container>
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll comment on the main question. By stateless do you mean not to use this.state and just use the props argument? (still won't compile with super();).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `semantic-ui-react` has been installed?

Comment: Yes. I have an entire app working, but I'm trying break parts out into sub-components. I want other users of this code to be able to replace this component with the same external grid row, but alternate contents without breaking the outer template and grid.

Comment: Try to add `super();` before `this.state = props.fyrevm`. Moreover your component should be a stateless component.